# Editing data in a CoreData application

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I have an application with 4 view, the main View is a view that contain my table view with some data, in this view I have also one button the Add button to add new data, if I click on a row I have the detailView and in this view I have a button and if i click it I have the editView, now I want to change the data, but when I type some data I can't save that. this is the code

```
-(void)save {
    [self.ricettaDaModificare setValue:self.titoloRicetta.text forKey:@"name"];
    [self.ricettaDaModificare setValue:self.ingredientiRicetta.text forKey:@"ingredient"];
    [self.ricettaDaModificare setValue:self.preparazioneRicetta.text forKey:@"make"];
}
```

I know that must pass the context but when? Thanks

Comment: Show us other details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call save on your managed object context after you have updated your database objects:

```
-(void)save {

    [self.ricettaDaModificare setValue:self.titoloRicetta.text forKey:@"name"];
    [self.ricettaDaModificare setValue:self.ingredientiRicetta.text forKey:@"ingredient"];
    [self.ricettaDaModificare setValue:self.preparazioneRicetta.text forKey:@"make"];

    NSError *error;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];

    if (error) // handle save error
}
```

Comment: He is asking about when passing the context, I suppose. :)